# How to write this java code without java.util.stream library on kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
var validPushes: MutableList<Push> = IntStream.range(0, pushQuantity).mapToObj { inx -> readPush()}
              .filter { push  -> processor.validatePush(push, state)}
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to write this java code without java.util.stream library?
I could not find an analog to mapToObj. map does not fit, because I need to cast it to Obj.
Collectros replaced by asSequense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a range to do the counting. You can convert the range to a sequence in order to keep the lazy nature of your `Stream`.

```
val validPushes = (0 until pushQuantity)
    .asSequence()
    .map { readPush() }
    .filter { processor.validatePush(it, state) }
    .toMutableList()
```